# Curl command for invoking a POST request with basic authentication and multipart file upload

Tags: curl, post, multipartform-data, basic-authentication

I am invoking the following service using a curl command:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authCredentials) {...}
```

It uses basic authentication and fileupload is needed as a multipart file.

How do I invoke this using a curl command?

I am trying this but getting an error saying illegal base64 character:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization:Basic username:password' -H 'Accept:application/json'    -F 'file=@./application.properties' http://hostname/api/uploadFile/
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Authorization:` header is wrong.

Let curl convert the user name and password to a HTTP authentication header instead with [-u](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u):

```
curl -i -u 'username:password' -H 'Accept:application/json' -F 'file=@./application.properties' http://hostname/api/uploadFile/
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would you include multiple files in the command above?

Comment: I have an API that uses a parameter called files instead of 'file' and digests multiple files. How can I add that here as : -F 'files = @./file1.properties, file2.properties'. Is this possible?

Comment: Nevermind, found this - https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76      We just need add files in the same file parameter separated by commas, it works